# Is "Hominum futurae" the right way to say "future man"?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

I want to call my project "future man". Is "Hominum futurae" is the right way to say this? If there is another good way to say this in Latin, please tell me.

Answer (score 12):

"Hominum futurae" is ungrammatical gibberish.

"Future man" (i.e. the man that will be) would be **homo futurus**.

Comment: Isn't ``homo futuris`` the common phrase?

Comment: @PatrickT that phrase is indeed found here and there, but back in actual Latin, *futuris* is the dative/ablative plural of *futurus/-a/-um*, so it is certainly out of congruence with *homo*. (You could have *hominibus futuris* in some context or other, but that is neither here nor there.)

Comment: I see, thanks! By analogy with homo heidelbergensis (Of Heidelberg), it seemed to make sense. But having said that, searching through google books doesn't return many uses. I found it in a 17th century book, "Atheismus triumphatus seu reductio ad religionem per scientiarium veritatem." But for some reason it has become a very popular phrase in more recent years. Several books with that title on amazon and other booksellers.

Comment: @PatrickT There are different kinds of adjectives in Latin with different sets of endings. The forms *futurus/facilis* are the same, and so are *futuris/facilibus*. The analogy doesn't, unfortunately, work.

Comment: Thank you, got it!

Answer (score 10):

While rare in this usage, one possibility that gibes with some more modern cultural references could be:

**Homo crastinus**, the "Man of Tomorrow".

Given the English phrase, it would have additional "futuristic" or even comic book connotations. You can compare Superman: The Man of Tomorrow, but more importantly Marvel's Phoenix: The Man of Tomorrow, or Disney's Tomorrowland. You get the idea.

Answer (score 9):

Allow me to offer yet a different route:

*Homo venturi saeculi*.

*Saeculum* is, of course, a “century,” but also “age” and, for example in Tacitus, the *Zeitgeist*, which perhaps is not altogether irrelevant here,

*Venturus* is in essence a synomym of *futurus*, but since it's not so insanely all over the place, it has, I think, its appeal.

(Evidently my proposal is a thinly veiled paraphrase of the *vitam venturi saeculi* at the very end of the Nicene creed.)